# Using Azure how do you list blobs in a container for Windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I want to list file names of the blobs in a container on my Azure server using Windows Phone 8.

I'm using this: `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.Phone.Storage;`

Library is: Windows Azure Storage Client Library for Windows Phone v1.0.1.

The library has been deprecated, but it's the only one that will work with WP8. (Unless someone knows of another one?)

Code:

```
ICloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containerName");
```

I'm not sure what arguments to pass to this:

```
container.ListBlobs()
```

Visual Studios recommendation is this:

```
Action<CloudOperationResponse<IEnumerable<ICloudBlob>>> callback
```

But I don't know what that is. Anyone know?

Comment: have you looked at this?

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#list-blob

Comment: Yea but its using CloudBlobContainer and not ICloudBlobContainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello yes the toolkit has been deprecated the other way is I think that you can start using the Windows Azure Mobile Services:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/

if you previously have worked on Windows Azure Node JS then you can easily build a new Windows Azure Mobile API that do the required action which is listing the blob and call this API from your Windows Phone application.

here is the resources of the NodeJS and how it uses the Windows Azure Blob Storage:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

to integrate it with the Mobile Services, just fo to your portal, create new Windows Azure Mobile Services and under API enter the NodeJS Code.  here is a link demonstrating how to work with it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/14/windows-azure-major-updates-for-mobile-backend-development.aspx

i hope this helps you, let me know if you need anything else.